# Prove superpolynomial growth rate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Let $p(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$.

Prove that growth rate of $p(n)$ is superpolynomial, meaning that for every given $k$ there is $p(n)= \omega (n^k)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of divisions" of $n$? If you mean the number of *divisors*, that can't be, since that's way less than $n$ itself. But maybe you mean the number of *partitions*. Look that up, and see if you can find the information you need. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564907/help-understanding-solution-to-growth-of-partition-function

Comment: It was my mistake - I mean partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $k$, the number of compositions of $n$ into $k+1$ parts is $\binom{n+k}k$, which is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $n$. The number of partitions of $n$ into $k+1$ parts is at least $\frac1{(k+1)!}$ times the number of compositions. This gives the required order of growth only considering partitions into $k+1$ parts, which of course is a lower bound for the total number of partitions.